# NameError issue with Desktop

Tags: python

I am new to python. 
I am trying to run my first script... I think this is what is called.
I have following in a python doc called "intro.py":

```
print('hello world')
```

This is saved under my Desktop (running Windows).
When I go to cmd, I type:

```
>>> Desktop/intro.py
```

When I do this I get a response that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Desktop' is not defined
```

Can someone please explain to me my issue? Thanks

Comment: don't type cmd commands in python shell. use windows shell.

Comment: Is windows shell like Notepad or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Windows shell refers to what you see, when you hit windows-button + r and then type cmd and hit enter.

To start your script: hit windows-button + r and then type cmd and hit enter

After that navigate in the command line to your desktop using `cd` and then type `python init.py` to execute your script.

It seems to me like you were already in the python shell, when you tried to start your script.

To see the difference open the command line like before: hit windows-button + r and then type cmd and hit enter, remember how your terminal looks like now, then type in `python` and note the three `>>>` at the beginning of the line. This is then called the Python shell.

You tried to execute windows commands in this python shell, which obviously does not work. However you could also theoretically write your script   in this python shell. But this is really awkward.

I suggest you to use an IDE. If I'm not wrong IDLE comes with the python 3 interpreter already or I can recommend my personal favorite PyCharm.